# I need to make a roof with a cut and drop and I don't know how to do it

Tags: modeling

The roof is normal and then it has a cut and falls on the two sides with an angle until it touches the wall.

[image: This is the roof, it's from a recording studio.]

Comment: What have you tried and why it didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Create a cylinder, then delete part of it so you only have an arch. This will be the basis for the roof. Then, select all of the edges that go up and down the arch, and subdivide them with two cuts. Finally, select all the vertices on the ends, and scale them along one axis to make them flat. You can use “snapping mode: vertex“ to move them along that same axis and align them with the bottom of the arch.